# How to convert a flattened PDF to PCL in LiveCycle process?

Tags: pdf, livecycle, printer-control-language

I am looking to convert a non-XFA PDF to PCL in a Workbench process and am not having any luck with geneartePrintedOutput service.  I retrieve a flattened PDF from Contentspace (using retrieveContent) and need to convert the non-XFA PDF to PCL without sending it to a printer right away.  Are we not able to achieve this with generatePrintedOutput? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know LiveCycle but what I do know is you could run the resulting PDF through [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/), via the command line, with the -sDevice=ljet5 (for example), this file could then be sent to the printer by copying it to the UNC of a share.

I believe you could even just put the UNC to the printer share as the output for Ghostscript like this:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ljet5 -sOutputFile=\\server\printershare\pdfdocument.pcl c:\pdfdocument.pdf
```

Otherwise, just put a filename in and then copy like this:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ljet5 -sOutputFile=c:\pdfdocument.pcl c:\pdfdocument.pdf
copy c:\pdfdocument.pcl \\server\printershare
```

You may also be able to simply pass in the PDF stream in memory to Ghostscript as it supports STDIN.

If you'd rather not just copy the file to a UNC you can pass the resulting file/bytes directly into a printer installed locally using C# or VB etc.
[How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091).